# How to extract all values from Json using SQL regardless of the different keys (wildcard with multiple pairs)?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-dynamodb, looker

Thank you first!

Basically, I have the following:

```
SELECT 
        parse_json(collection."Name".values)
FROM some_table_name
```

This will return me:

```
{ "en": "Jack", "fr": "Jack", "ch": "杰克" }
```

And I can access ONE of the values as:

```
SELECT 
        parse_json(collection."Name".values):en
FROM some_table_name
```

And it will return me "Jack" as a string in one row

Now question please:
How do I return all the values regardless of the key in all the pairs so that I can get "Jack", "Jack" and "杰克"(3 rows are preferred)?

Thanks again!

Comment: You can first get the Keys and then use them to get the Data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Added! Thank you for the kind reminder!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry for being such a trouble it was DynamoDB